# Flutter Apple Sign In - Empty Email

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I am trying to add "Apple Sign In" to my Flutter iOS app using the [apple_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/apple_sign_in) package.

The code is mostly working.  My problem is that the call to `_firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)` is creating a firebase account that has a null identifier (please see screenshot below).

One weird thing about this is that when the user selects the option to share their email address when signing up, `result.credential.email` contains the user's email address after the call to `AppleSignIn.performRequests()`. So I'm really puzzled as to why the user's email is not being used as the identifier when the account is created in Firebase.

```
  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithApple() async {
    final AuthorizationResult result = await AppleSignIn.performRequests([
      AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email, Scope.fullName])
    ]);

    switch (result.status) {
      case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        final AppleIdCredential appleIdCredential = result.credential;

        OAuthProvider oAuthProvider =
        new OAuthProvider(providerId: "apple.com");

        final AuthCredential credential = oAuthProvider.getCredential(
          idToken: String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.identityToken),
          accessToken: String.fromCharCodes(
              appleIdCredential.authorizationCode),
        );

        await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        return _firebaseAuth.currentUser();

        break;

      case AuthorizationStatus.error:
        print('Sign in failed: ${result.error.localizedDescription}');
        break;

      case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
        print('User cancelled');
        break;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 35):

I believe this is working as intended;

Apple only returns the full name and email on the first login on the device for your app, it will return null values for these on any login after that. My guess is that you've signed in previously and then tried to sign-in again via a new Firebase Auth user and the Name/Email is no longer available at that point.

For testing purposes, to receive these again; go to your device settings; **Settings > Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store** > **Password & Security** > **Apps Using Your Apple ID, tap on your app and tap Stop Using Apple ID**. You can now sign-in again and you'll receive the full name and email again.

This is how Apple has designed their API - so it's recommended that you store these elsewhere on your app, e.g. using the shared_preferences plugin - so that you consistently have access to them when required.

Comment: Yes, indeed! That is Apple's Sign In Design. Just realized that all credentials are only retrieved once

Comment: Thanks, stack on this a very long time. Now understand why I am not getting the email & name.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! However resetting the usage of the App for Apple ID does not make the email appear again for me. Does someone else have the same problem or is the problem just an emulator thing?

Comment: It has been changed to Settings > Apple ID > Sign-In & Security > Sign in with Apple > ... based on iOS 17.2 and iPhone 15.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is iOS 13.6 in 13.5 I got Name, email, token, id. but in iOS 13.6 only return de user ID. I use the sign_in_with_apple dependency (https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple).

Comment: I am getting the same thing with iOS 14. Do you know if there is a solution for this?

Comment: Did you found a solution please ?

Comment: same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are perfect but I'm sharing some cases those I tried after doing all the above answers and then I didn't get the email either *(Even didn't even ask me whether I wanted to share the email or not in login)*. I faced this for flutter but it might work for IOS too.

1. If you are in development, Go **Settings** -> **Password & Security** -> **Sign in with Apple** -> **YOUR_APP_NAME** ->  **Stop using Apple ID**
2. Remove blank email named user from **Firebase console** -> **Authentication** -> **Users**.
3. Add scope **'email'** *(If you need full name then add 'fullName' or anything you want in scope)* like that-

   ```
        final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
        appleProvider.addScope('email');
        var credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
   ```

After that, a popup shows if I want to share the email or hide it to login. Handle the case for IOS, If the user **Hide** the email sharing if the popup.

Comment: FirebaseAuth docs don't mention the scopes. Also, adding the email scope adds the ability for user to `Hide My Email`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Anyway, I couldn't find a scope called 'fullName' but there is a scope called 'name' and can use it to get the user name.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use firebase to authenticate, get the user's email from firebase user, just do it ...

```
User? user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow("apple.com", ["email"], {"locale": "en"});
```

And then get the data from the user like...

```
var email = user.email;
```

Answer (score 0):

the user email and name and other information returned by AppleLogin will be null after the first time if we didn't revoke the access_token for that user.

all you need to do, is to revoke the access token which has been generated at the first login and then try to login once again.

you may use the following request for **getting that access token** :

```
 await post(
    'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token',
    {
      'client_id': com/package.name,
      'client_secret': clientSecret,
      'code': authorizationCode,
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'redirect_uri': ''
    },
```

and use this request for **revoking the access token**:

```
 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke'
'client_id': com.package.name,
      'client_secret': clientSecret,
      'token':token
```

you will need to generate client secret using private key, you may follow this link for how generate that. token:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accountorganizationaldatasharing/creating-a-client-secret

this also helpful : [Medium article on how to generate client secret through dart](https://martin-robert-fink.medium.com/generating-apple-client-secret-with-dart-28f29a55f8f0)