# Flutter iOS sign in with apple not showing email after revoking token

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-ios, apple-sign-in

With the apple user deletion policy

> Apps that support account creation must also offer account deletion to give App Store users more control of the data they've shared while using your app.

I successfully refresh and revoked the token with the apple id and deleted the user from firebase.

But when deleted user tried to login again using **Sign in with apple** it's not showing email or username. When user sign in with apple account I am creating a user in firebase, for the first time is working good, when user deleted their account and tried to logged-in again the email is empty.

I am using the below code to retrieve email and name for the logged in user.

```
      // Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
      final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
        scopes: [
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
          AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
        ],
        nonce: nonce,
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

same error with me, get email with first time signing but after that don't get email and receive null.
I fount this solution [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174889/flutter-apple-sign-in-empty-email) But not the best solution, If you find a solution, please reply here.